# structure padding with bit fields

Tags: c, structure, padding

I want to make a structure with 36 bits So I tried the structure below

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
 struct{

    unsigned int a : 5;
    unsigned int b : 1;
    unsigned int c : 11;
    unsigned int d : 2;
    unsigned int e : 2;
    unsigned int f : 1;

    unsigned int g : 8;
   unsigned int h : 6;

}HDR;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

sizeof(HDR): 5, 8*5 = 40 bits, I tried with unsigned short still its 40 bits.

But I wanted to use only 36 bits.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use something like `unsigned char HDR[36]`? Also remember the size of int is not the same across different compilers and platforms.

Comment: This code is screaming for the `<stdint.h>` header

Comment: If I use unsigned char HDR[36] thats 36 Bytes rights But I need 36 bits with bit fields

Comment: You won't get 36 bits unless you're on a machine that has a 36-bit word size, and those are few and far between these days.  The total size will always be an integral number of bytes, and hence the bits will always be a multiple of CHAR_BITS (which is probably 8 on your machine).

Comment: You might also REALLY want to be careful with ordering.  Depending on the machine you are compiling for, the endianness could become an issue depending of course on your use model.  I have generally used bit fields for embedded systems that are supposed to directly read and write hardware registers.  In these cases you REALLY have to watch bit and byte ordering!!!

Comment: Sorry I misread you needed 36 BITs, sizeof(HDR) is 8*4BYTES = 32Bytes on most platforms (int is "usually" 4 bytes). I would probably use a `unsigned char[5]` will get you the close as possible. Since you are dealing with bits you'll probably be using bitwise operators anyways so just ignore the extra space you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an object is always a multiple of `sizeof(char)`. A `char` holds `8` bits on most platforms. To accommodate `36` bits, you will need an object whose size is equal to `5*sizeof(char)` and you get `40` bits.

You will need a object of size `5` to hold `33` - `40` bits.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1. Saying the object size will always be a multiple of 1 is not very useful :). The size will be a multiple of `CHAR_BIT` (defined in limits.h).

Answer (score 0):

Many machine have a minimal size of 8 bits, so you can't get to 36 bits in any fashion.  There will always be packing bits to get it to an 8-bit or 16-bit or 32-bit boundary.